# Nested for loop in java. Am I allowed to declare a variable in the outer and increment it in the inner?

Tags: java, variables, loops, for-loop, declaration

I want to use nested for loops to bring the elements of a 2d array into a 1d array. Can i do it with an index variable declared in the outer loop and incremented in the inner one like this?

```
for(int i=0, l=0; i<a; i++){
        for(int j=0; j<b ; i++; l++)
            narray[l]=oldarray[i][j];
        }
```

Got it to work now, by doing this:

```
int l = 0
for(int i=0; i<a; i++){
  for(int j=0; j<b ; i++){
       narray[l]=oldarray[i][j];
       l++;
 }
}
```

Comment: Have you tried this example?  Surely that would answer your question.

Comment: You don't seem to modify `i` or `l` from within the inner loop...

Comment: I've added an l++ in the loop parameters, I'm also working on making an example program, just to try it out, but I'm not very fast, so I figured i might as well post it here, and someone will probably beat me to it.

Comment: Ok, now I saw that i had put a k there as well.

Comment: Typically it is expected that people attempt to solve the problem themselves before posted a question here.  Then people asking questions can post their progress toward an answer and the learning process goes so much more smoothly. :) Also, the variable name `l` is usually discouraged because it looks so much like a `1`.

Comment: Ok, thank you very much :) Not entirely used to The Coders Creed yet, sorry for that.

Comment: @BjørnHaugerud look at my answer, maybe it will help you to solve your problem

Answer (score 0):

So you have a matrix (Multi dimensional array) with number of 'a' rows and 'b' columns
and you want to turn this matrix into one dimensional array.

```
   int l = 0
   for(int i=0; i<a; i++){
     for(int j=0; j<b ; j++){
      narray[l]=oldarray[i][j];
      l++;
     }
   }
```

this code is valid in java.. but look at the inner for loop.. just the first line next to the for loop will be execute so the variable `'l'` will remain 0 until the inner loop will finish the loop.. so in this case you just set the first element of the new array..

so you need to change the code.. 
the new array length will be a*b   (rows*columns)

```
  int l = 0
  for(int i=0; i<a; i++)
  {
      for(int j=0; j<b ; j++)
      {
         narray[l]=oldarray[i][j];
         l++;
      }
   }
```